# Swift AVMutableVideoComposition scale and center calculation

Tags: swift, scale, center, crop, avmutablecomposition

I am scaling a AVMutableVideoComposition to fit my full screen view.

When I do this it scales from the bottom left corner so I am trying to center it. here is my code...

```
let scale = max(videoViewBounds.width/source.extent.size.width, videoViewBounds.height/source.extent.size.height)
        let screenScale = UIScreen.main.scale

        let translateX = (source.extent.size.width * scale) - videoViewBounds.width
        let translateY = (source.extent.size.height * scale) - videoViewBounds.height
        print("X: ", translateX)
        print("Y: ", translateY)

        let sourceTransform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: scale * screenScale, y: scale * screenScale).translatedBy(x: -translateX/2, y: -translateY/2)

        overlayFilter.setValue(source.transformed(by: sourceTransform), forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)
```

This gives me a result very close to what I want, but it is ever so slightly off. if I change

```
-translate/2 to -translate/1.5
```

it seems to be perfect. But I don't understand why.

Any ideas? or a better way to scale and center?

Thanks

Comment: What size is the `source`? And the `videoViewBounds`?

Comment: The size of the source is dependent on the size of the original video size recorded for example could have a width of 480, or 720, or 1080 etc. (recording in portrait). The videoViewBounds is the size of the screen bounds depending on the phone.